# Rotating a Tabular Chart and a Nontabular Title to Fit the Page

Tags: tables, pdftex, rotating, charts

I am working on producing a tabular chart that is too large to be presented on a page in portrait form; so I would like to rotate it (as well as its title which is technically not part of the tabular chart) -90 degrees so that it may be vertically read from bottom to top on a single page.

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}
\hfill {\Large{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{{Title and Chart to be Rotated -90$^\circ$}}}}\hfill} 

\vskip 15pt

\begin{tabular}{l*{12}{c} | l}

Victories & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & Ties \\

{} & Nov & Dec & Jan & Feb & Mar & Apr & May & Jun & Jul & Aug &
Sep & Oct & {} \\

{} & XI & XII & I & II & III & IV & V & VI & VII & VIII & IX & X &
{} \\

Item 1 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & {} & {} & {} \\

Item 2 & {} & {} & {} & 9 & {} & {} & {} & 16 & {} & {} & {}
& {} & {} \\

Item 3 & {} & {} & {} & 7 & {} & {} & {} & {} & 16 & {} &
{} & {} & {} \\

Item 4 & {} & 24 & {} & 10 & {} & {} & {} & 15 & {} & {} &
{} & {} & {} \\

Item 5 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} \\

Item 6 & 8 & {} & 73 & 35 & 35 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {}
& {} & {} & 1 \\

Item 7 & {} & {} & 11 & 3 & 6 & 5 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & 2 \\

Item 8 & 43 & 56 & 3 & 1 & 10 & 55 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & {} \\

Item 9 & 11 & 45 & 37 & 28 & 37 & 20 & {} & {} & {} & {} & 17 &
{} & {} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

QUESTION: How may I rotate both the (red) nontabular title and the tabular chart -90 degrees so that it may vertically fit on one page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibilities is to use `sidewaystable` defined in the `rotating` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    
\hfill {\Large{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{{Title and Chart to be Rotated -90$^\circ$}}}}\hfill}

    \vskip 15pt
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{12}{c} | l}
Victories & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & Ties \\
{} & Nov & Dec & Jan & Feb & Mar & Apr & May & Jun & Jul & Aug &
Sep & Oct & {} \\
{} & XI & XII & I & II & III & IV & V & VI & VII & VIII & IX & X &
{} \\
Item 1 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & {} & {} & {} \\
Item 2 & {} & {} & {} & 9 & {} & {} & {} & 16 & {} & {} & {}
& {} & {} \\
Item 3 & {} & {} & {} & 7 & {} & {} & {} & {} & 16 & {} &
{} & {} & {} \\
Item 4 & {} & 24 & {} & 10 & {} & {} & {} & 15 & {} & {} &
{} & {} & {} \\
Item 5 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} \\
Item 6 & 8 & {} & 73 & 35 & 35 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {}
& {} & {} & 1 \\
Item 7 & {} & {} & 11 & 3 & 6 & 5 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & 2 \\
Item 8 & 43 & 56 & 3 & 1 & 10 & 55 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & {} \\
Item 9 & 11 & 45 & 37 & 28 & 37 & 20 & {} & {} & {} & {} & 17 &
{} & {} \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. This works quite nicely.