# How to Prevent \Sidewaystable from Beginning on a New Page

Tags: pdftex, rotating, resize, sidewaystable

This post is an extension of the question posed in [Rotating a Tabular Chart and a Nontabular Title to Fit the Page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620400/rotating-a-tabular-chart-and-a-nontabular-title-to-fit-the-page)

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 9.75in \textwidth 5.75in
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{THIS IS THE TABLE INTRODUCTION}}
\end{center}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\hfill {\Large{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{{Title and Chart to be Rotated -90$^\circ$}}}}\hfill}
\\[15pt]
\centering
\resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l*{12}{c} | l}
Victories & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & Ties \\
{} & Nov & Dec & Jan & Feb & Mar & Apr & May & Jun & Jul & Aug &
Sep & Oct & {} \\
{} & XI & XII & I & II & III & IV & V & VI & VII & VIII & IX & X &
{} \\
Item 1 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & {} & {} & {} \\
Item 2 & {} & {} & {} & 9 & {} & {} & {} & 16 & {} & {} & {}
& {} & {} \\
Item 3 & {} & {} & {} & 7 & {} & {} & {} & {} & 16 & {} &
{} & {} & {} \\
Item 4 & {} & 24 & {} & 10 & {} & {} & {} & 15 & {} & {} &
{} & {} & {} \\
Item 5 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} \\
Item 6 & 8 & {} & 73 & 35 & 35 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {}
& {} & {} & 1 \\
Item 7 & {} & {} & 11 & 3 & 6 & 5 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & 2 \\
Item 8 & 43 & 56 & 3 & 1 & 10 & 55 & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} &
{} & {} \\
Item 9 & 11 & 45 & 37 & 28 & 37 & 20 & {} & {} & {} & {} & 17 &
{} & {} \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

which (unfortunately) produces the 2-page output:

[image]

I would like to point out that I have intentionally produced a very, very small table to illustrate that ample space exists on the first page for containing it; yet, it seems that some default is causing it to start on the following page.

QUESTION: How may I display my sideways table immediately beneath the introductory title on the same page? Remark: Even when I run the code without resizing the table, it seems that the table should be small enough to fit nicely on the previous page.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not possible. `sidewaystable` as well `sidewaysfigure` always start on the new (next) page where is inserted. In your case you need to rotate table (figure) only. For example with use of `\sideways` environment.

Comment: As `Zarko` said, use `\begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}` or `\begin{rotate}{90}...\end{rotate}` instead of `\begin{sidewaystable}...\end{sidewaystable}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi It seems that `rotate` is the best choice of all as I can specify the angle of rotation---in my case, -90. Can one specify anything further with `sideways` (such as 90 degrees or -90 degrees)? Thank you for your helpful comment. All things considered, `rotate` seems to suit me best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `OP`s comment, I've derived my comment as `suggestion`.

As `Zarko` said, use `\begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}` or `\begin{rotate}{90}...\end{rotate}` instead of `\begin{sidewaystable}...\end{sidewaystable}`, and the `MWE` is:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{rotate}{90}% or whatever you like
...
\end{rotate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. It seems to me the simplest way to take care of the table portion of the problem I posed; although the side title, it seems to me, would have to be handled in a different manner.

Answer (score 2):

The `sidewaystable` environment rotates a minipage whose width is `\textheight` so it will always be on a page by itself. As a matter of style, setting a table sideways is something that should be avoided unless it's absolutely necessary so trying to do what you want is most likely a bad idea.

So the question becomes, how can we make what you want work given that it's a bad idea and you should definitely definitely *not* do this?

There are two approaches. One is to take advantage of the (usually undesired) fact that `tabular` is set in horizontal mode (which is why it does weird things in a lot of contexts). This means that if we write:

```
\begin{table}
 \begin{sideways}
   \begin{tabular}{...}
     ...
   \end{tabular}
 \end{sideways}
\end{table}
```

We get exactly something that takes exactly the horizontal space of the enclosed `tabular`. Note, however, that if you put anything outside the `tabular` environment within the `sideways` environment, you will get unexpected and undesired results.

So, if you wanted to rotate a caption along with the table, another approach would be to define an new environment which I'll call `sidewaystable'`¹ that takes a mandatory argument which will be the desired height of the `sidewaystable`.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sidewaystable'}{m} 
   {\setlength{\textheight}{#1}\begin{sidewaystable}} % ❶
   {\end{sidewaystable}}
```

The magic here is that we'll lie to `sidewaystable` about what the `\textheight` is so that when it produces its output it will make the rotated box have a smaller height.

But we're not done. Presumably, you wanted to have your sideways table printed at the bottom of a page. LaTeX will not put a large float at the page bottom by default. So, we need to adjust a couple other parameters to make this work. In particular, you'll need to do

```
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
```

to floats on the bottom of the page take up to 85% of the page. You may need to adjust this per your needs. Be aware also when choosing the height for your `sidewaystable'` that in addition to keeping it less than `.9\textheight` (or whatever fraction you've chosen), that you also need to leave room for there to be `\textfloatsep` space (by default 16–22pt with an ideal size of 20pt) between the text and the `sidewaystable`.

You'll also need to lower the minimum amount of space that LaTeX will include with a float if you've set `\bottomfraction` greater than `.76` with

```
\RenewExpandableDocumentComand{\textfraction}{.1}
```

The default value for `\textfraction` is `.2`, but you'll have noticed that I'm setting things up so that `\textfraction` + `\bottomfraction` < 1. This is intentional since `\textfloatsep` is in addition to the text box and the float box and you need to leave a bit of space.

---

1. Yes, you can put `'` into an environment name. You can put almost anything into an environment name, in fact.